# Python Tkinter: Create tree with Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, checkbox, drag-and-drop, treeview

I am trying to create a custom tree using Canvas.

The tree consists of text labels and will have checkboxes. Drag and drop should be available too. I do not intend to use ttk.Treeview or Tix.

It would be great if examples can be provided. Thank you

Python 2.7, Linux

NOTE: I need 2 trees side by side

Comment: This is possible, but it will require significantly more work than using pre-built solution... Are you absolutely certain you don't want to use such solutions?

Comment: Yes, because I only have read-permission to the shared libraries, so I cannot install Tix and our ttk is outdated

Comment: I see, I'll have a think on it.

Comment: I can use idlelib.TreeWidget, but still need to experiment with it. I need 2 trees side by side in a frame, and hopefully I can add checkboxes